# Mikrotik configuration lost after electricity went off

Tags: networking, router, mikrotik

Because of electric went off the miktrotik router lost operation system  ..
The operation System went down ..

I did backup to the router "ccr1009"
After that everything went well but I got this massage

Pptp connections are considered, it is suggested to use a more modern VPN protocol instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question, although the answer is most likely backups.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Mikrotik is suffering from this issue, when you disk size is full.
Make sure to remove your backups if you have limited disk space.